# Variables not being passed to class method

Tags: php, class, methods

I'm building a login class with PHP, but the variables used are empty when I pass them to the class method even though they shouldn't be.
I tried returning only the $username variable but it's still empty, though if I return it without using the class I can see that it gets assigned correctly.

I'm using multiple other classes with methods where the variables gets assigned correctly.

I don't know if i've stared myself blind and am missing something obvious or if there's something else causing this.

```
class Auth
{
    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct(mysqli $mysqli)
    {
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public function login($username, $password) //These variables are empty, even when they shouldn't be
    {
        $return['error'] = true;

        $uid = $this->getUserId(strtolower($username)); //Returns false because $username variable is empty

        if (!$uid) {
            $return['message'] = 'No such user.'; //Output
            return $return;
        }

        $user = $this->getUser($uid);

        if (!password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
            $return['message'] = 'Password incorrect';
            return $return;
        }

        $return['error'] = false;
        $return['message'] = 'Logged in';

        return $return;
    }

    private function getUserId($username)
    {
        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($id);

        if ($stmt->num_rows < 1) {
            return false;
        }

        $stmt->fetch();

        return $id;
    }

    private function getUser($uid)
    {
        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password, email FROM users WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $uid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($username, $password, $email);

        if ($stmt->num_rows < 1) {
            return false;
        }

        $stmt->fetch();

        $return['uid'] = $uid;
        $return['username'] = $username;
        $return['password'] = $password;
        $return['email'] = $email;

        return $return;
    }
}
```

A form assigns the variables sent.

```
<form method="POST" action="post.php">
    <label>Username
    <input style="display:block;width:250px;" type="text" name="username" required></label>
    <label>Password
    <input style="display:block;width:250px;" type="password" name="password"></label>
    <button style="display:block;" class="default_btn">Log in</button>
</form>

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $auth = new Auth($mysqli);
    $auth->login($username, $password);

    if ($auth->login()['error']) {
        echo 'error:' . $auth->login()['message'];
    } else {
        echo 'success:' . $auth->login()['message'];
    }
}
```

EDIT:

If I assign the variables in the class method the code works:

```
public function login($username = 'user', $password = 'pass')
```

But if I do this, it will not work:

```
$username = 'User';
$password = 'pass';

$auth = new Auth($mysqli);
$auth->login($username, $password);
```

Also, if I use the $_POST values outside of $auth->login() they are assigned so they are not empty when passing them to the class...

Comment: what do you get if you do a `var_dump` before calling `$auth->login` and first thing inside the method? maybe $_POST is empty.

Comment: Code seems fine, I would check if both the variables are set before you submit them with var_dump

Comment: I checked it real quick and my test variables come through just fine. I'm 99% sure that the POST variables are simply empty

Comment: Both variables are set, if I use them outside the class they work as intended but when I pass them to $auth->login() they are not.

Comment: @Crecket if ($auth->login()['error']) { } always returns true for me. Could you show me how you tested it?

Comment: Even though it may sound strange but the <form> uses method=Post?

Comment: Try adding `print_r(get_func_args());` to see what variables are being parsed to the function. And in my test file i replaced $_POST with a random value

Comment: try to send hard coded username and password to check weather its problem with class code or the POST variables.

Comment: @NeerajVerma If I do public function login($username = 'user', $password = 'pass') the code works as intended. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, of course.

Comment: @Crecket I've updated the question.

Comment: Just a side-note, you're using prepared statements, yet you construct the sql *by hand*. Don't!

Comment: @Yoshi Could you elaborate? I'm doing the connection with $mysqli = new mysqli(); in an included config file.

Comment: here `"SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'"` you inject the variable directly into the sql string (=> *constructing by hand*). Doing this is just as dangerous as not using prepared statements. Instead you should do something like `"SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username` and later `$stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));`.

Comment: @Yoshi Ah, I see. I will get to that as soon as I get this working as intended.

Comment: @Yoshi I did this instead:
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
should be about the same as what you described?

Comment: put a `var_dump($username, $password, __FILE__.__LINE__);` as the first line in the `Auth::login` function. This will ensure that the correct `class` is being used.

Comment: @RyanVincent this outputs: `NULL NULL string(53)`

Comment: @RyanVincent `array(0) { } NULL NULL string(53)` Even if I assign the variables manually they're not getting passed to the method, it only works if I assign them in the method like I've described in the question.

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes. I do this: `if (isset($_POST['username'])) { }` before calling the class. I can echo the variables successfully from inside that block etc.

Comment: @RyanVincent When I `var_dump` I get NULL as value. I have updated the question with the actual form and the processing script.

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes, I know it is a superglobal. I use several other classes with $_POST values in the methods and they work as they should. I'm banging my head over this. :|

Comment: @RyanVincent I don't know why, from what I can tell it doesn't make any difference if I use <button> or <input>. The posted code is broken down from what I would use if this worked, just so that I could test the class. I would use `header` to send the user elsewhere when pressing log in, if this worked.

Comment: @RyanVincent Anyways, I separated it from everything else, now I get `array(2) { ["username"]=> string(4) "User" ["password"]=> string(4) "pass" } string(53) "D:\Apache24\htdocs\includes\classes\eauth.class.php14" array(2) { ["username"]=> string(4) "User" ["password"]=> string(4) "pass" } string(53) "D:\Apache24\htdocs\includes\classes\eauth.class.php14" array(2) { ["username"]=> string(4) "User" ["password"]=> string(4) "pass" } string(53) "D:\Apache24\htdocs\includes\classes\eauth.class.php14" error: No such user.` when doing `var_dump`. It still doesn't work though.

Comment: ```$auth->login()['message'];```should generate an error?

Comment: @JohnSvensson No, it displays the message assigned to it, depending on where the code returns.

Comment: @RyanVincent I'm using PHP 5.6.10. Thanks, I'm curious to what results you'll get.

Comment: Glad it was sorted out :-)

Comment: @RyanVincent Yea, thanks for all the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you don't store the result and instead call login again without values: `if ($auth->login()['error']) {`.

Try this:

```
<form method="POST" action="post.php">
    <label>Username
    <input style="display:block;width:250px;" type="text" name="username" required></label>
    <label>Password
    <input style="display:block;width:250px;" type="password" name="password"></label>
    <button style="display:block;" class="default_btn">Log in</button>
</form>

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $auth = new Auth($mysqli);
    $login_result = $auth->login($username, $password);

    if ($login_result['error']) {
        echo 'error:' . $login_result['message'];
    } else {
        echo 'success:' . $login_result['message'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! This did it, can't believe I didn't think of it myself but I guess that's what happens when you've been staring yourself blind. Thank you so much!